# Image Tracking using AR.js - Problem with Custom Image Descriptors

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I am trying to generate an AR scene using Image Tracking based on the [tutorial in AR.js documentation](https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/image-tracking/). When I was using the sample URL as provided in the [demo](https://codepen.io/nicolocarpignoli/pen/vYOeYKd) in Codepen, it worked but when I specified the URL to be the path to my own generated image descriptors in my local machine, I got this error:

> "Error in loading marker on Worker 404"

Since it was working well when I used the image descriptors provided in the demo, I assume it's something to do with the image descriptors that I generated, I am actually using the same [image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/examples/image-tracking/nft/trex-image-big.jpeg) provided in the demo too so I don't think the problem is with the quality of the marker.

Here is my code `aframe-ar.html`:

```html
<a-scene
      vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;"
      renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;"
      embedded
      arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam;debugUIEnabled: false;"
>
    <a-nft
      type="nft"
      url="../image_descriptors/test"
      smooth="true"
      smoothCount="10"
      smoothTolerance=".01"
      smoothThreshold="5"
    >
        <a-entity
              gltf-model='https://arjs-cors-proxy.herokuapp.com/https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/examples/image-tracking/nft/trex/scene.gltf'
              scale="5 5 5"
              position="100 100 0"
        >
        </a-entity>
  </a-nft>
      <!-- static camera that moves according to the device movemenents -->
  <a-entity camera></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
src 
  | -- image_descriptors
         | -- test.fset
         | -- test.fset3
         | -- test.iset
  | -- assets
         | -- aframe-ar.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test it using XAMPP. I don't know why but if you see the console, there is log

> base path: http://localhost:8080

So i tried

```
<a-nft
    type="nft"
    url="test/image_descriptors/test"
    smooth="true"
    smoothCount="10"
    smoothTolerance=".01"
    smoothThreshold="5">
```

with this folder structure:

```
htdocs (basically http://localhost:8080)
| -- test
     | -- image_descriptors
          | -- test.fset
          | -- test.fset3
          | -- test.iset
     | -- assets
          | -- aframe-ar.html
```

and it works

Comment: a little late, but it was the problem with the path, thanks!